# Cancelling Ripple With A 7555

Tags: ripple, emf

Friends, I did this once but don't remember the detail. A very sensitive circuit which switches a relatively heavy load. I used a 7555 IC to momentarily blank out any ripple or instability caused by the switching. It was feedback from the 7555 output to another pin on the 7555. A very useful circuit, but I have lost the diagram. What was it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it. Very useful for disabling a sensor circuit, say, for the while that the output does the heavy work.

[image: Ripple Cancel]

Comment: If you are going to give an answer to your own question and that original question is unanswerable by anyone but yourself (due to lack of both clarity and concise requirements), then expect the question to be closed as unclear. If that does not concern you into making the question clear and obvious, then please delete the question.